# Rhythmbox default radio stations missing

Tags: rhythmbox

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a new machine yesterday and started Rhythmbox. There were several default radio station (iradio) preloaded there. I started a stream and did reboot the machine some time later.

After the reboot all radio stations are missing from Rhythmbox.

I tried reinstalling rhythmbox, tried deleting `.local/share/rhythmbox` ... but nothing.

I just want to get the default stations back, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the approach below doesn't work, here is an original `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<rhythmdb version="1.8">
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>WSUM 91.7 FM (University of Wisconsin)</title>
    <genre>College Radio</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://vu.wsum.wisc.edu/wsumlive.m3u</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>WKNC 88.1 FM (NC State) (High Quality)</title>
    <genre>Music</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://wknc.sma.ncsu.edu:8000/wknchq.ogg.m3u</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>WKNC 88.1 FM (NC State) (Low Quality)</title>
    <genre>Music</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://wknc.sma.ncsu.edu:8000/wkncmq.ogg.m3u</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>HBR1.com - Dream Factory</title>
    <genre>Ambient</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://ubuntu.hbr1.com:19800/ambient.ogg</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Absolute Classic Rock (Modem)</title>
    <genre>Rock'n'Roll</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=vc</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Absolute Classic Rock (Broadband)</title>
    <genre>Rock'n'Roll</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=vcbb</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Absolute Radio 90s (Broadband)</title>
    <genre>90's</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a9bb</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Absolute Radio 90s (Modem)</title>
    <genre>90's</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a9</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>HBR1.com - Tronic Lounge</title>
    <genre>House</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://ubuntu.hbr1.com:19800/tronic.ogg</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Absolute Radio (Modem)</title>
    <genre>Pop</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=vr</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Absolute Radio (Broadband)</title>
    <genre>Pop</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=vrbb</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>KWUR 90.3 FM St. Louis Underground Radio</title>
    <genre>Unknown</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://www.kwur.com/icecast/kwurogg.m3u</location>
    <play-count>1</play-count>
    <last-played>1376592165</last-played>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>wbur.org - Boston's NPR news source</title>
    <genre>News</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://audio.wbur.org/stream/live_ogg.m3u</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>StartFM - 94.2MHz, Vilnius University, Lithuania</title>
    <genre>Underground</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://eteris.startfm.lt/startfm.ogg</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Absolute Radio 80s (Modem)</title>
    <genre>80's</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a8</location>
    <play-count>1</play-count>
    <last-played>1376592232</last-played>
    <bitrate>32</bitrate>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Absolute Radio 80s (Broadband)</title>
    <genre>80's</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a8bb</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>HBR1.com - I.D.M. Tranceponder</title>
    <genre>Trance</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://ubuntu.hbr1.com:19800/trance.ogg</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Radio Paradise (High Quality)</title>
    <genre>Eclectic</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://stream-tx1.radioparadise.com:9000/rp_192.ogg</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
  <entry type="iradio">
    <title>Radio Paradise (Low Quality)</title>
    <genre>Eclectic</genre>
    <artist></artist>
    <album></album>
    <location>http://stream-sd.radioparadise.com:9000/rp_96.ogg</location>
    <date>0</date>
    <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
  </entry>
</rhythmdb>
```

Answer (score 3):

Quit Rhythmbox. Run the following command in terminal and start Rhythmbox.

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.rhythmbox.plugins.iradio initial-stations-loaded false
```

Note, that this will restore only the default radio stations that got shipped with Rhythmbox.

Source: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/FAQ#How_do_I_restore_the_default_list_of_radio_stations_.3F

Answer (score 2):

1. Shut down Rythmbox.
2. Then do this in a Terminal window...

   `$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge rhythmbox`

   `$ sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`

   `$ rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml`

   `$ touch ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml`
3. Then launch Rythmbox, and your radio stations should be back.

(Remember to accept this Answer, so I know it worked for you).

Comment: as said, i already tried this, it does not solve the issue. The default radio stations are still missing

Comment: You already said you tried reinstalling and deleting .local/share/rhythmbox.  You didn't say you did this: touch ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml  (Read carefully!)

Comment: true, but even when touch'ing the file rhythmbox just creates an empty library. i ended up copying the rhythmdb.xml file from another machine which is still not helful for someone who has no other machine :) i will still mark your answer as helpful as soon as i have enough reputation as it points out which file is the file to mess around with.

Comment: A fresh install of Rythmox should automatically populate an empty rhythmdb.xml file with the default radio stations (that's why we delete the file, and then "touch" it).  But if the empty file does not exist, it will not setup the default stations.

Comment: Lynx, this is a good idea!... I know you already have it, but I posted the file here, in case someone else needs.

Comment: Marvellous, this worked for me on `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`.